# List of integer to List of list of Integer in Python

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, integer

I have list of integer as [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7] I want to convert this to 'list of list of integer' as [[1], [2], [4], [5], [6], [7]].

`[list(i) for i in p]` as it throughs 'int' object is not iterable Error
[list(str(i)) for i in p] but this would give me [['1'], ['2'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7']]

any help please? I tying this with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list()` function takes an iterable as input and converts it into a list containing members of iterable. That is why you see the error that `int` is not iterable.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> [[i] for i in a]
[[1], [2], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
>>>
```